# How to Sync my data saved in plist with web server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

i am using plist to save my data locally when network connection is not available, and when network is available i want to sync my locally saved data to the web server.

i am using this code. but i dont know whether the data is saved in server or not.

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example url"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file://my plist file"];
NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:filePath progress:nil completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Success: %@ %@", response, responseObject);
    }
}];
[uploadTask resume];
```

i am assigning my api to the URL in which i want to save the data of plist, and my plist to the filepath in which my data is already saved. can anyone solve this issue.

Comment: Did you implement any code that continuously check for internet availability even on background? First do that, uploading is the second thing.
Look for the answer here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38691583/detecting-internet-connectivity-continually

and then add the uploading code that you might be using in your project in the ReachableViaWWAN or ReachableViaWiFi case.

Comment: yes of course i have implemented code for checking network connection

Comment: Then include the afnetworking via pods and look for the uploading snippet under afnetworking documentation. Replace the file name with your plist.

Comment: can you please give an example code.

Comment: Look under 'Creating an upload task' in https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#usage

Comment: my project getting crash and the reason is "[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you use normal API Call to stored pList file to a server. **Becuase when you read plist file, your will data in NSDictionary and you send it server to store.**

To read value from plist:

```
NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YOUR_PLIST_NAME" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dicData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

To send this dictionary to server, you can use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

To Stored valude into plist:

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsPath = paths.firstObject;
 NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"File.plist"];
 NSError *writeError = nil;
 NSDictionary *finalDict = @{@"Objects": objects};
 NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:finalDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:NSPropertyListImmutable error:&writeError];
 if(plistData){
     [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
 }
 else {
     NSLog(@"Error in saveData: %@", error);
 }
```

Comment: my project getting crash and the reason is "[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter"

Comment: how to check the plist data which i have saved previously

Comment: in my project i have created a plist file

Comment: Its in bundle or your stored in cache memory??

Comment: i have stored it in bundle

Comment: Checkout your path and name of plist.

Comment: my data is not getting stored in plist

Comment: Lets connect over Skype nirmalsinh.creolestudios